# How can I supply arguments from variable value to the command in shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, java

I am trying to make a shell script in which I want to pass the `-classpath "classpath-value"` flag to the `javac` command. I know I can use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to set the classpath, but I have a very specific need to do it this way.

What I want:

```
$ classpath_val="-classpath \"/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/lib/servlet-api.jar\""
$ javac $classpath_val com/example/Test.java
```

However, when I executed the second command, it just executes as if the classpath_val were not supplied, so it doesn't use the `-classpath flag`.

But if I echo the same command, I get:

```
$ echo javac $classpath_val com/example/Test.java
javac -classpath "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/lib/servlet-api.jar" com/example/Test.java
```

Which is perfectly right.

Why is this happening? Is it that I can't supply arguments to a command from variable value?

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for giving the solution. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, probably the most robust way to do this is using an *array* e.g.

```
classpath_val=("-classpath" "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/lib/servlet-api.jar")
```

then expand each element in a whitespace-safe way using

```
javac "${classpath_val[@]}" com/example/Test.java
```

Quoting the elements in both the array construction and expansion prevents them from being split on whitespace. To illustrate:

```
$ arr=("foo" "bar baz")
$ set -- "${arr[@]}"
$ for f; do echo "$f"; done
foo
bar baz
```

Comment: Is it possible to put the classpath value in double quotes. Because a space anywhere in classpath value will break it.

Comment: @KashyapKansara spaces should not break it if you use quotes as I have shown - do you have a specific example where that's not the case?

Comment: @steeldriver Hey...sorry...sorry...It is working perfectly fine with spaces. I have just checked it. Thank you for taking time to answer my question.